# How to query an edit rejection?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14956549

Either the rejection was a mistake or I'm misunderstanding something about how the system works.

From what I can see - the edit is fixing a typo in the code - my call to super was referencing the wrong class. The edit from Rajan fixes that.

3 reviewers said "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner." - why would they say that?

1. Shall I just make the fix myself?
2. How do I contact the reviewers to ask about their reasoning?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266467/suggested-edits-that-change-code/266479#266479

Answer (score 31):

It is the *edit comment* that is at fault here:

> Change from ArticleOptions to VehicleAdmin

Yes, we can see that that is what the edit does. What it fails to tell reviewers is **why** the editor made that change. The diff doesn't tell us that, it just shows the edit changed something (the editor indeed changed `ArticleOptions` to `VehicleAdmin`).

The assumption then is that this change breaks something rather than fix it, reviewers are generally very conservative when it comes to changes to code. It is the editor's job to explain *in the editing comment* what the change is for.

Had the editor used a different comment, the review would have gone different too:

> Fix error in the code: change the class passed to super(); it must match the class the method is defined in. Presumably this was a typo made by the author.

I've now made the change directly.

Since it is your own post, if a suggested edit you agree with has not made the grade, just apply it manually yourself. A review, once approved or declined, is closed and can't be revisited.

Comment: Again, this is pure rubbish. If I can't fix mistake on someone post, we may as well not have edits at all! If someone doesn't want others to edit their post, SE is simply not the site for you. Editing other people posts are a feature!

Comment: @Braiam: Yay, and calling 'this' (without any specific reference) 'pure rubbish' is going to fix all that.

Comment: @Braiam: I happen to know Python and understand what the error is. However, it is *somewhat obscure*, and the edit could have been vandalism, just as much. The reviewers were correct in rejecting it, they had 0 context to do otherwise. Your rant is without substance here.

Comment: @Braiam: so you rather have reviewers just approve stuff that makes a noble claim to replace A with B everywhere. Next up: Meta will be filled with rants about all the bad edits being approved, and calls to punish reviewers harder.

Comment: The whole "reviewers can't be blamed" analogy. [I've had this problem *since eons ago*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199584/213575), and if meta continues to put the burden on the editor rather than reviewers to do the right call, we aren't going anywhere near SE *raison d'etre*: have a library of high quality programming answers.

Comment: "so you rather have reviewers just approve stuff that makes a noble claim to replace A with B everywhere." NO! I detest you make such leap logic. Reviewers should *review*, if they can't review, they should skip. Pure and simple.

Comment: @Braiam: then that edit would have been left in limbo forever. Next up: why doesn't anyone review suggested edits anymore? Scale plays a huge role here too.

Comment: "then that edit would have been left in limbo forever." Oh, come on! The author came to meta because he could have reviewed that edit. He almost catch the reviewers. So that not an issue. "why doesn't anyone review suggested edits anymore?" For the same reason nobody do chores. It's a drag.

Comment: @Braiam Reviewers can't be blamed? On the contrary: it is the editor's job to present a case to the reviewer, to help them, as much as possible, to come to a decision. If they can't meet that low bar (self-expression, self-justification), why should a reviewer waste any time on it?

Comment: @jpaugh I've had seen several times on meta where the editor explained pretty explicitly and clear why were they doing their edits, yet they have been rejected, until I remember that reviewers have [tunnel vision](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315855/792066) and never read the whole post.

Comment: @Braiam Life happens. And I agree with your premise: reviewers have much room to improve. But if the editor can't get it right, then it becomes the reviewer's burden to reverse-engineer the motivation for the edit;  and in some cases, the edit is already a lost cause before a reviewer sees it, because it doesn't explain well.

Comment: @jpaugh well, if they had no such time or can't invest their effort, they could skip. At the end of the day, someone will know enough to do due diligence to the edit, but rejecting or approving in a knee-jerk reaction is simply not useful.

Comment: **Moderator note**: Not that this discussion is going anywhere anymore. Can I suggest people take this to chat now?

Answer (score -2):

> Either the rejection was a mistake or I'm misunderstanding something about how the system works.

The latter. Edits to code should generally be rejected, if they change the meaning, unless they fix obvious problems with the code. The reviewers are not meant to have domain knowledge to verify the validity of the edit. The edit is somewhere in between: One has to know the language to see that it's a obvious mistake.

See also [FAQ: When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)

> Shall I just make the fix myself?

Since it's your answer, you can do whatever you want, so yes.

Comment: "Edits to code should generally be rejected" [citation needed]

Comment: @Braiam for further details I'd refer to the linked FAQ page

Comment: Well, arguably step 1 of the linked FAQ was violated: *"When in doubt, click 'Skip'. "Learn to love that Skip button.""* Aside from that…the FAQ *also* clearly says that fixing typos in answers is perfectly valid. So no, the edit was not at fault here—it's just that the *justification* offered for the edit wasn't very obvious. Please stop spreading the harmful myth that code is somehow "off limits" for edits.

Comment: @CodyGray I'd argue it is 'off limits' in **questions**, as it could be (and usually is) the cause of the problem. I agree that in answers that's not the case, but editors should explain clearly their reasoning to avoid this kind of problems IMHO.

Comment: Well sure. Don't edit out typos in code that are critical to the question. Not coincidentally, the linked FAQ covers that. @tensbai

Answer (score -25):

> why would they say that?

Because reviewers are a bunch of monkeys <s>pushing</s> clicking buttons (we have audits for that reason).

Look, without someone sane making the right calls, trusting the reviewers to do the sensible thing is impossible. You, as the author of the post, can simply apply the edits yourself.

> How do I contact the reviewers to ask about their reasoning?

There's no way to do that... at least not without leaving a comment on a unrelated post.

Ultimately, this is why reviewers need to skip more edits. They didn't know you made a "typo" or that the editor was just fixing it, because they are incapable of doing a sensible review.

Recommended reading:

- [Edit rejected for not making post accurate; it does](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340745/792066)
- [Suggest to me what tag filtering I should use in review next](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254145/213575)
- [The Community vs. The Domain Expert](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339101/792066)