# How to get a review for a rejected suggested-edit?

Tags: support, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

I had submitted an edit on an answer on Stack Overflow available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610239/grouping-googletest-unit-tests-by-categories/12615706#12615706).

Suggested Review details are available from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23867983).

I had provided justification [available from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074520/why-compiler-complain-about-this-macro-declaration) of why the edit was needed since the existing answer was providing an incorrect solution.

How can I challenge the rejection for probably more voting consideration since the edit is actually improving the answer?

Comment: Edits are not for making major changes to code, if you think the answer is wrong downvote it and write your own answer.

Comment: I agree with @greg-449. I'd have rejected this as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That was a very bad edit suggestion and the reviewers were correct to reject it. On Stack Overflow, [edits that change code are highly discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266479/6471538). The problem is not that we don't want people to suggest better code (we do), but that using edits to do so breaks the Question and Answer format of the site.

- "Fixing" the code in a question can invalidate the premise of the question, especially if the question was asking for debugging help.
- "Fixing" the code in an answer may inadvertently break functionality.

Instead of suggesting a change to code, *post an new answer* with your new code and *explain* why it is better than the other answers!

Comment: To point out the issue with the framing of the question here another way -- the suggested edit *already got a review*, and the review resulted in rejection of the edit.

Comment: There's also the possibility of adding a comment to the answer explaining what you perceive the problem with the code to be.  This can prompt an edit to fix the problem, or a comment back on why it isn't one.

Comment: Or add a comment.